# VirtualBox guest addition works incorrectly

Tags: linux, virtualbox, resolution, gentoo, guest-additions

I installed Gentoo on a virtual machine and
[guest addition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cfTX.png) too.

I checked that it works. For example, I can drag and drop a file from the host to the virtual machine and back. I also have a shared clipboard. But the [screen resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpvBr.png) has not changed. I would like to put at least 1920x1080, help me fix this problem ;-)

Here is xrandr output:

```
user@localhost ~ $ xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       0.00* 
   800x600        0.00  
   640x480        0.00
```

Comment: I was having a similar problem with my openSUSE VM. I had to go into the VM Setttings > Display .... and change Graphics Controller to VBoxSVGA

Comment: @n8te, I shutdown machine, change Graphics Controller and still same. Should I reinstall VBoxAddition, will this help?

Comment: @n8te no, it's not.

Comment: You can try that VMSVGA Graphics Controller setting as well. That one is supposed to be for Linux, although with my openSUSE VM that one didn't help but the VBoxSVGA one did. But still, give VMSVGA a try.

Comment: @n8te, I just tested all three VBoxVGA, VBoxSVGA and VMSVGA, nothing changes ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Check which driver is in use with `lsmod`.

Comment: @LucasRamage `user@localhost ~ $ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
vboxguest             188416  3
`